# does this triply nested do loop produce false sharing in OpenMP Fortran?

Tags: optimization, concurrency, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I am trying to parallelize a code I inherited from someone.
I am still learning about OpenMP.

I know that if multiple threads bounce back and fort a cache line and at least one of them writes to it, then that is a bottleneck.

Is this what happens here? I am thinking that 2 consecutive elements of `U2` are very close in memory and not at least 1 cache line apart, thus false sharing?
Thank you!

```
       !$OMP PARALLEL DO COLLAPSE(3) FIRSTPRIVATE(Vt, aivar, t,
!$OMP+ dt, ri, y, phi) SCHEDULE(STATIC)
       do l = 0, lmax
       do m = 0, nphi-1 
       do j = 1, Nb                   

         Vt = Ez(t+dt/2d0) * ri(j) * y(l)
     &      + Ex(t+dt/2d0) * ri(j) * dsqrt(1d0-y(l)**2) * dcos(phi(m)) 
     &      + Ey(t+dt/2d0) * ri(j) * dsqrt(1d0-y(l)**2) * dsin(phi(m)) 

         U2(j, l, m) = U2(j, l, m) * cdexp(-aivar * Vt * dt)

       end do
       end do
       end do
       !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

where before the above, at the start of the subroutine declaration and implementation, I have:

```
   real*8 t, ri(Nb)
   real*8, dimension(0:lmax) :: y
   real*8, dimension(0:nphi-1) :: phi

   ! Local variables
   complex*16 U2(Nb, 0:lmax, 0:nphi)
   integer j, l, m
   real*8 Vt
   real*8 :: Ez, Ey, Ex ! functions

   integer :: Nbvar
   complex*16 :: aivar
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with Fortran but it looks fine to me (as long as `l` and `m` are private which should be the case here due to the collapse I guess). There are written cache lines that will likely be shared so there is some form of false-sharing but it should not be much a problem unless you operate on a relatively small array on a many core system, and in that case, the main issue should be the small amount of work, not much false sharing. Why do you specifically focus on false sharing?

Comment: @JérômeRichard, thank you. I am not familiar with Fortran either, as I inherited the code from someone else. I was concerned with this because I have seen from SO posts that this can be a bottleneck. As I don't understand it in great detail, I said it's better to ask. I was thinking that I shall only parallelize the outer do-loop and in this way each thread would get 2D arrays, and operate on their elements, which might be a better chance to avoid bouncing back and fort the cache-lines?

Comment: There are many other issues that can happen when you parallelise a code. It is a waste of time to consider every issue that can happen and unjustified to focus on a specific one. The best thing to do is certainly to profile so to check if there is an issue in the first place. If so, then you can check such a thing. If profiling results are good, then there is no reason to worry about this.

Comment: One issue with collapsed loops (unrelated to false sharing) is that they are sometime not efficiently implemented by the target OpenMP implementation. Some of them (eg. GCC/GOMP) use a div that can be pretty expensive if the items are fast to compute. This is why collapsing can actually be slower (but not the only problem though). Because of this, it is generally good to collapse loops only if you know the amount of parallelism provided by the target loop is not enough. This is not easy in some cases since you may not know the target platform running the code.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, thank you. I will try changing the order of the loops such that the one having the largest range is on top and then parallelize only the outer loop without the collapse statement. would it help to see the OpenMP implementation I am using? I am compiling with ifort on a cluster and the maximum no of cores I can request is 24.

Comment: This is not the only thing to consider for performance. The access to the arrays needs to be as much contiguous as possible (unless the operations is mainly compute-bound) so to reduce cache misses, especially `U2`. Also the compiler can precompute some terms regarding the order. For example `dsqrt(1d0-y(l)**2) * dcos(phi(m))` can be precomputed for all `j` in your current loops but it will likely not be the case if you move the `j`-based loop first. Regarding the OpenMP implementation, it is generally the one provided with the compiler used so IOMP+Ifort here.

Comment: I advise you to read a high-performance computing book if you are not familiar with such things, especially if you often deal with such problem. Alternatively, you can just try many change of the code and keep the fastest one, but you will not learn a lot. As the famous proverb said: "*Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime.*" ;) .

Comment: 1. You are using `firstprivate` where you should be using `private`. 2. Make sure your loop variables `l,j,j` are private. 3. OpenMP gives each thread a consecutive chunk, so as long as you keep the `j` loop innermost, there is no problem with false sharing.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, thank you! Can you please elaborate a bit on the ``firstprivate`` issue? I thought I need to have the variables initialized when they are "sent" to the pool of threads. If ``ri``, `y``, ``phi``, ``dt`` , ``aivar``, ``t`` would be ``private``, wouldn't they be sent with non-initialized values? The only variable for which I see it shall be ``private`` is ``Vt``. Correct?

Comment: The variable `vt` is set, so `private` is enough. the variable `t` is only read, so you can keep it `shared` by default.